# React + Websocket not triggering onmessage event once the application is idle for some time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, chat

I am creating a Realtime Chat Application using React UI and WebSockets, and a backend of AWS API Gateway.

The Application works fine when it has activity, but once it goes idle for some time, the React UI stops reflecting messages received on 'onmessage' trigger OR 'message' event.

```js
this.socket = MessengerService.getSocket(this.props.tokenStore.token as string, this.props.mode.toLowerCase())
    
this.socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  const message = JSON.parse(event.data)
  audio.play()
      
  this.setState({
    messages: [
      ...this.state.messages,
      message
    ]
  })
      
  this.scrollToLatest()
})}
```

I also have a MessengerService which is based on Singleton socket instance,

```js
export class MessengerService {
  private static mode: string;
  private static wsUrl: string;
  private static socket: any;
  private static instance: MessengerService;
  private constructor(token: string, mode: string) {
    MessengerService.mode = mode
    MessengerService.setURL(token, mode)
    MessengerService.socket = new WebSocket(MessengerService.wsUrl)

    MessengerService.socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log('connected')
    }
    
    MessengerService.socket.onerror = (error: any) => {
      MessengerService.socket.close()
    };
    
    MessengerService.socket.onclose = (event: any) => {
      console.log('disconnected')
      MessengerService.reconnect()
    }

    MessengerService.socket.addEventListener('message', (event: any) => {
      const message = JSON.parse(event.data)

      if (checkNotificationPermission()) {
        showNotification(message.content)
      }
    })
  }

  public static getSocket(token: string, mode: string) {
    if (!MessengerService.instance) {
      MessengerService.instance = new MessengerService(token, mode);
    }

    return MessengerService.socket;
  }

  private static setURL(token: string, mode: string) {
    MessengerService.wsUrl = `${APP_CONSTANTS.CHAT_WS_BASE_URL}/chat?Authorization=${token}&userType=${mode.toLowerCase()}`
  }

  public static sendMessage(message: string) {
    // Wait for socket to connect
    if (MessengerService.socket.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {

      const wait = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('waiting for connection')
        if (MessengerService.socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          MessengerService.socket.send(message)
          clearInterval(wait)

        }
      }, 100)
    } else {
      MessengerService.socket.send(message)
    }
  }

  public static async reconnect(): Promise<WebSocket> {
    const token = await getCurrentToken()

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {

        console.log('reconnecting')
        MessengerService.setURL(token, MessengerService.mode)
        MessengerService.socket = new WebSocket(MessengerService.wsUrl)
        resolve(MessengerService.socket)
      }, 1000)
    })
  }
}
```